# Is there a software that make it possible to edit all exif values and add new paramerers?

Tags: metadata

A while ago I had the need to add cutom fields to my exif 
(some programming staff)

I found out that most of the fields are locked and that I cannot add new fields
Do you know a software that can
1. Cancel the lock of exif fields edit
2. Enable fields adding.

Comment: What makes you think they're "locked"?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there is a library which can change + add exif meta data: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openexif/

So I'm wondering what your source was that said the fields are locked?

There is also a very good tool called [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) which allows very extensive changing of the meta information.
There is however a [warning about changing meta data](https://exiftool.org/writing.html), you have to know what you're doing.